# Excel VBA Close and Re-Open same workbook on a timer

Tags: excel, vba, loops, timer

I have Program.xlsm running on a main hub computer.  I want to enable other computers on the network to view the workbook (read only) that the main hub is constantly updating. The code runs on the opening of the Program.xlsm workbook.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

sHostName = Environ$("computername")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If sHostName = "MAIN" Then
    'Run code on a timer that includes re-saving Program.xlsm with new data.
Else
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:01:05"))
    Set w = ThisWorkbook
    Set w2 = Workbooks
    src = "Program.xlsm"
    Set wb1 = w2.Open(Filename:=src, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True)
    w.Close
End If

End Sub
```

I was expecting users on the network to be able to open "Program.xlsm", The program would wait 65 seconds and then open a second instance of Program.xlsm, and then close the first instance of Program.xlsm, and continue every 65 seconds after.  But it doesn't seem to be doing anything.

What am I missing?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to *(temporarily)* share the workbook instead? Much less memory hogging as well!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "share".  I am unfamiliar with that and how that would work.  I need the ability to auto-refresh on a users computer.

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to do. If the data can be updated by users, just share the workbook using the inbuilt share function and the data will refresh itself upon change. If you just want the data to be refreshed use `ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll` on a timer instead of opening and closing the file.

Comment: RefreshAll does not do anything for me.